# Get entry from list by name

Tags: c#, forms, linq, list

I have a List of Forms:

```
List<Form> xxx = new List<Form>();
```

How can I find out whether it contains any Form identified by a certain name, something like:

```
xxx.Contains()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use FindAll function

```
List<Form> xxx = new List<Form>();
int count = xxx.FindAll(x => x.Name.Equals("YourFormName")).Count();
```

Comment: if you count, you can just do `xxx.Count(x => x.Name.Equals("YourFormName"))`

Comment: Right, but I prefer show the FindAll function for another use of return ist :)

Comment: Thanks, this helps to find if exists.

Comment: I have else question: It's possible to get index of the form bases on this code? for today i have foreach but i think that is easy way to do this.

Comment: The goal for me is: i need to get instance of the form if exists - i know only name of form

Comment: Use Controls[index] and Controls[name] to get your desired form :)

Comment: Thanx for your answer ;) a finnaly use FindIndex method :) now code looks better :)

Comment: Ya it should be better ! Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list.Where(r => r.Name == "YourName").ToList();
```

EDIT: (as per codesparkle)

Since you are checking whether a form with a Name exists in your list of forms, you may get the count of result and see if it is greater than 0

```
if(result.Count > 0) 
{
//Form found in the list
}
```

A better approach in your case would be to use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

You can do:

```
if (list.Any(r => r.Name == "YourName"))
    {
    //Form found in the list
    }
```

Remember you have to include `System.Linq;` in your using statements.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I *would* find it helpful if you could extend your answer (e.g. `bool contains = result.Count() > 0`) and add an explanation, possibly linking to msdn...

Answer (score 0):

You have not really shown what you are doing, but this is what you should be doing:

With `Contains`, you can only check whether the specified instance is in the list. Instead, you can use the `Enumerable.Any` method to check for an arbitrary predicate:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

xxx.Any(item => item.Name == yourDesiredName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following [LINQ expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx):

```
var forms = from form in FormList  
            where form.Name == "A_FORM_NAME"
            select form;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your List and return the first `Form.Name` matching your search term:

```
foreach (Form form in xxx) 
{
    if (form.Name == "Whatever") 
    {
        return form.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Why you don't just put a property for each form that define each form from the other.

Then you can check this property for each form instance

Comment: please include a code example to clarify what you are trying to say. To me, this answer makes no sense at all.